# How to schedule a bot message in Discord.js v14 (Slash commands)?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I need to schedule some messages for users and I would like to do this with the bot. If possible choosing the date and time of the message.

I'm very new to this part so I'm asking for help.

In my code, I add a .js file for the command inside the commands folder.

By default, commands start with:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
  name: "schedule", // Coloque o nome do comando
  description: "Schedule messages.", // Coloque a descrição do comando
  type: Discord.ApplicationCommandType.ChatInput,
  options: [
    {
        name: "schedule",
        description: "Schedule messages.",
        type: Discord.ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
        required: true,
    }
],

  run: async (client, interaction) => {
```

Comment: What part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: It's actually not a problem. I would like to know what code I add to be able to create this scheduling command.

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout() for making shedules

```js
setTimeout(() => {
   console.log("Shedule is running");
   //Do whatever you wanted to do when the time comes
   //...
}, 3000)//3000 = 3 seconds
```

Comment: This is not the way

Comment: @Vince I mean you could schedule any message or event with it right? In their case, They wanted to schedule a message. So they could send a message in that callback function